# How to get FrameRate of the video on HTML5 Video element

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I am developing a time-lapse video player using `HTML5 Video element` and is controlled by mouse (touch) events. The problem is that the videos which will be played are encoded at a different ***frame rate***, not fixed like common 24 FPS. In native platforms such as iOS, there is a native API which provides video's frame rate. I am wondering if is there any similar API on HTML5 Media API. Without this information, I cannot play a video smoothly on my player.

Answer (score 1):

Mozzila Developer Network does not list any methods for finding the framerate of a media element. However, there is an experimental method called [`seekToNextFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seekToNextFrame) which could be used to advance frame by frame. This is only supported by firefox behind a flag.